# Can't update the specific key of state variable

Tags: reactjs

So, I have a checkbox having onchange method but in the method, I am not able to change the value.

Also, the value received is the same as key in the state variable.

Following the code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={pins:[],filter:{Irrigation:true,Patvan:true,Drinking:true,Minigrid:true,Rooftop:true}}
    this.handleFilterChange=this.handleFilterChange.bind(this)
}

handleFilterChange(filtervalue){
    console.log(filtervalue) //lets assume value to be Drinking
    console.log(this.state.filter[filtervalue]) // it says true
    this.setState({filter[filtervalue]:!this.state.filter[filtervalue]}) //here the error occurs
}
```

I know i am doing some syntax mistake. Help in pointing it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the state using `filter[filtervalue]` as property key, you should do something like this:

```
this.setState(
  prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    filter: {
      ...prevState.filter,
      [filtervalue]: !prevState.filter[filtervalue]
    }
  })
)
```

First, if you need to access the previous state during an update of the state, you should use the method tecnique, not the object one.

Then, updating an inner property of the state can be a bit cumbersome as you see, my suggestion is to use something like `immer`.

Comment: The first decontruction of prevState isn't necessary but this is a coreect solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all when your state changes depend on the current state use the `updater` method of `setState`. After that since you are updating a nested object you need to recreate the nesting up to the property you need to update.

In your case the object passed to `setState` should be

```js
{
  filter: {
    Irrigation: true,
    Patvan: true,
    Drinking: false, // this is what changed
    Minigrid: true,
    Rooftop: true
  }
}
```

So your actual `setState` call should be

```js
this.setState(({
  filter // destructure the original state and extract the filter property
}) => ({
  filter: { 
    ...filter, // spread the existing  filter properties
    [filtervalue]: !filter[filtervalue] // overwrite the property that changed
  }
}))
```